# Sliding divs navigation

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, sliding

i'm working on a site which have links to the left and a content area on the right. I would like to get it to slide in and out using jquery like this site: http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/44960.html

This is my current code (could get jFiddle to work?)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
body { 
        /**background-image: url(../img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        **/
        background-color: red; 
        background-image: url(img/bg.jpg);
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        height: 100%; margin: 0; width: 100%;
}
html,body { height:100%; }
#left {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    width: 220px;
    background-image: url(img/panel_bg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    height: 100%;
}
#right {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    width: 630px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div.panel {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 620px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background-image: url(img/content_bg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    display: none;
}
</style>
<script type="text/Javascript">
jQuery(function($) {

    $('a.panel').click(function() {
        var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
            $other = $target.siblings('.active');

        if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
            $other.each(function(index, self) {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.removeClass('active').animate({
                    left: $this.width()
                }, 500);
                $($target).hide();
            });

            $target.addClass('active').show().css({
                left: -($target.width())
            }).animate({
                left: 0
            }, 500);

        }
    });

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="left">
    <a href="#target1" class="panel">Target 1</a><br/>
    <a href="#target2" class="panel">Target 2</a><br/>
    <a href="#target3" class="panel">Target 3</a><br/>
</div>

<div id="right">
    <div class="panel" id="target1">Target 1</div>
    <div class="panel" id="target2">Target 2</div>
    <div class="panel" id="target3">Target 3</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How can i make it like the website i linked to? mine only slides over eachother, and not out to the right and in from left or vers versa

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/T7LzN/  Here's a jsfiddle with your code. If I figure something out, I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have [updated your code](http://jsfiddle.net/T7LzN/3/) to get the content sliding in and out. I changed a few styles to make it look a little clearer in jsfiddle since I didn't have your background images.

I changed your jQuery variables to not use $ at the beginning (personal preference) but otherwise it is the same. I removed the "panel" class on your links and changed the way floating was set up on the left and right divs.

```
 <a href="#target1">Target 1</a><br/>
```

Comment: This breaks the back button. To clarify. If I click target 1, then target 2, then target 3,. then hit back some content overlaps.

Comment: Yeah, Stian will probably need to do something in his javascript code to handle that case. The site he linked doesn't support the back button at all.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working pretty much as intended with some CSS changes. I just used `position:fixed` on the menu, and `position:absolute` on the sliding areas. I changed the background colors on the slides to ensure it's working. I didn't touch your jQuery. http://jsfiddle.net/T7LzN/2/